# Can I edit the html of an existing Ionic Component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my particular case I'm using the range slider in Ionic, ie:

```
<ion-range min="5" max="180" step="5" formControlName="time"></ion-range>
```

But I'd like to add the value, aka `{{ frmGoals.value.time }}` directly onto the `.range-knob`'s innerHTML.

My desire to do this would be to achieve something like this in the Ionic Framework, rather than Swift: https://github.com/Ramotion/fluid-slider. My only guess is either to manipulate the DOM to force this value in as you are sliding - or to directly edit the component HTML.

Comment: You could achieve something similar to this by overriding the default CSS of the ion-range component. But since the circle around the range-knob's value has a fixed width and height, the value should be less than 4 digits to fit inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the response @99tharun, however - without the value actually being appended to the innerHTML of the `.range-knob` CSS alone won't be able to solve my query.

Comment: The value is already there inside `.range-pin`. If you change it's `z-index` and `transform`, the value will be always visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below styles to your `app.scss` file:

```
  .range-md .range-pin{
    z-index: 5;
    transform: translate3d(0,28px,0) scale(.9);
  }
  .range-md .range-pin::before{
    display: none;
  }
  .range-md .range-knob-pressed .range-pin::before{
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-s4drjv

Comment: Perfect. Thank you mate!